# Sub-menu when using document.getElementById("nav01").innerHTML

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
document.getElementById("nav01").innerHTML = 
    "<ul id='menu'>" +
    "<li><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>" +
    "<li><a href='calendar.html'>Calendar</a></li>" +
    "<li><a href='photos.html'>Photos</a>
    <ul><li><a href='Test.html'>test</a></li></ul></li>"+
    "<li><a href='events.html'>Events</a></li>"+
"</ul>";



/*Navagation CSS*/
ul#menu {
  padding: 0;
  margin-bottom: 11px;
}

ul#menu li {
  display: inline;
  margin-right: 3px;
}

ul#menu li a {
  background-color: #CCC;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #696969;
  border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

ul#menu li a:hover {
color: white;
background-color: black;
}

ul#menu li a:active{
  background-color:blue;
}
```

This is the script code that I am using to create my menu. The problem i am having is i can not get the test menu to work like a sub menu. If it is not in there the Menu works like it should.

This is the full script code

I have added the CSS Code as this might help with the look i am trying to achieve

Comment: Post the complete code.. this isn't helpful to understand the actual problem..

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
document.getElementById("nav01").innerHTML = 
"<ul id='menu'>" +
"<li><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='calendar.html'>Calendar</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='photos.html'>Photos</a>
"<ul><li><a href='Test.html'>test</a></li></ul></li>"+
"<li><a href='events.html'>Events</a></li>"+
"</ul>"
```

the inner `<ul>` must be part of a `<li>` of the outer `<ul>`

also refer to

http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML_lists#Nesting_lists

how do you want this to appear?

when i got to

http://www.w3schools.com/html/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_intro

i see

[image]

is this not what you want?

Comment: That did not work,The way the code is my menu will not show up.

Comment: please see the edit and explain what the desired output is

Comment: I have added the CSS that i am using. This will give you the format that I am trying to use

Comment: must have something to do with your css, logically, the html seems fine. try playing with the display and padding parameters for ul